# How to write typescript typeguard method for function type

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, type-safety, narrowing

```
export const isFunction = (obj: unknown): obj is Function => obj instanceof Function;
export const isString = (obj: unknown): obj is string => Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object String]";
```

I want to write isFunction method - similar to isString, but typescript/eslint gives me an error:

```
Don't use `Function` as a type. The `Function` type accepts any function-like value.
It provides no type safety when calling the function, which can be a common source of bugs.
It also accepts things like class declarations, which will throw at runtime as they will not be called with `new`.
If you are expecting the function to accept certain arguments, you should explicitly define the function shape  @typescript-eslint/ban-types
```

Is there any way to do this?

**P.S. Here is the answer:**

```
export const isFunction = (obj: unknown): obj is (...args: any[]) => any => obj instanceof Function;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the warning is clear... You can detect that you have a function, but you can't infer much about parameters/arity/return-type. That info just isn't available at run-time. It tells you that you can't be certain about how to call the function, or what it returns (at build time).

If it's a risk you feel confident about, disable the warning.

`// tslint:disable-next-line: ban-types` on the line above.

Alternatively, type `(...args:any[]) => any` might be a good stand-in for `Function`, but a function of this type is no more type-safe than before.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the interface [`CallableFunction`](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_es5_d_.callablefunction.html), making your typeguard functions like this:

```
export const isFunction = (obj: unknown): obj is CallableFunction => obj instanceof Function;
```

In this way, the type of your function is separated of the constructor ones (which could be typed with the type `NewableFunction`).

Answer (score -5):

JavaScript has `typeof` operator that returns a string indicating the type of the operand. For your case, it can be used like this:

```
export const isFunction = (obj: any) => typeof obj === 'function';
```

`isFunction` will return `true` if `obj` is a function

Comment: The idea here is to write a type-guard. This answer completely misses the point.

Comment: thanks for your answer @rtarasen, but we speak here about typescript types

Comment: @AuthorProxy Although the suggestion to use `typeof obj === 'function'` is a more idiomatic means of testing the JS type here.